# Cannot send email to domain-based email addresses

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I'm not an expert on DNS and MX configurations, so any help on this would be appreciated.

The problem is my website cannot send out emails to the domain-based email addresses.

- website is www.example.com
- website **can** send emails to *@gmail.com or any other email addresses
- website **cannot** send emails to *@example.com (they just don't receive any emails)
- The domain-based emails work fine when used regularly (not being sent out from the website)
- Domain is registered with Network Solutions
- Website is hosted with GoDaddy
- Only www, @, and * A Records are set to point to GoDaddy
- Everything else (including the MX Records) are remaining the way they were before
- The emails used to work fine before we moved to GoDaddy

Answer (score 0):

Contacted GoDaddy and they said they needed to turn off emails on our plan to fix this issue.